# [rospack] Error: package 'my_first_ros_pkg' not found

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello dear members!
I am a beginner to ROS. I am following a book named "**ROS Robot Programming**" written by Turtlebot3 developers. i am writing my code according the book.
first i type these commands for creating CPP file.

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src/my_first_ros_pkg/src/
$ gedit hello_world_node.cpp
```

then build the package. then i go to Catkin workspace to build the package.

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make
```

till here everything goes well.
but when i try to run the node then it says Could not read parameters..

```
 ibrahim@ibrahim-Aspire-V5-591G:~$ cd catkin_ws
ibrahim@ibrahim-Aspire-V5-591G:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
ibrahim@ibrahim-Aspire-V5-591G:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun ros_package_template ros_pack
[ERROR] [1520428539.543254493]: Could not read parameters.
ibrahim@ibrahim-Aspire-V5-591G:~/catkin_ws$
```

Your help will be appreciated. Please comment about it. Thanks.

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284491/%5Brospack%5D-error:-package-%27my_first_ros_pkg%27-not-found/) by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2018-03-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-06**:
Have you run `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` after `catkin_make` completed? If not, `rospack` cannot find the package(s) in your `catkin_ws`.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-06**:
@Ibrahim_aerospace Welcome! I believe doing what @gvdhoorn says should help you. However, it's *always* a good idea to include a copy and paste of the full error using the `101010` (*preformatted text*) button vs saying paraphrasing the error.

**Comment by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on 2018-03-06**:
sir thank you very much for your precious reply. you are right i didnt include all the details actually i just made this account, a few ago moments ago. i wanted to upload the pictures. but as my account is new and i have no votes to upload the picture. sorry for this.

**Comment by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on 2018-03-06**:
@gvdhoom thanks i will try with this.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-06**:
No worries. The site blocking you from posting screenshots of the error worked in everyone's favor. Images aren't the best medium for text. You should copy and paste code, errors, and terminal output using the *preformatted text* (`101010`) button.

**Comment by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on 2018-03-07**:
@gvdhoorn your help is needed please. I changed the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ibrahim@ibrahim-Aspire-V5-591G:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun ros_package_template ros_package_template.launch
> ```

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named ros_package_template.launch below /home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/src/ros_best_practices/ros_package
```

`rosrun` does not work with `.launch` files. It only works with executables. As you are passing it the path to a `.launch` file, you get this error.

Either run your executable directly (using `rosrun`), or use `roslaunch` to start launch files.

---

Edit:

> ```
> ibrahim@ibrahim-Aspire-V5-591G:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun ros_package_template ros_pack
> ```

```
[ERROR] [1520428539.543254493]: Could not read parameters.
```

This error is not related to your initial problem/question. It would be better to ask this question in a new ROS Answers question.

Before you do that however, take a look at how the book does things, because parameters are typically set with `.launch` files, so starting a single node in isolation with `rosrun` is not necessarily supposed to work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on 2018-03-07**:
sir thanks for help. now error is `ibrahim@ibrahim-Aspire-V5-591G:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bashibrahim@ibrahim-Aspire-V5-591G:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun ros_package_template ros_package_template [ERROR] [1520405600.763644369]: Could not read parameters. ibrahim@ibrahim-Aspire-V5-591G:~/catkin_ws$`

**Comment by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on 2018-03-07**:
so is there any problem with my code ? please reply me. bunch of thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-07**:
I don't see any error in what you copy-paste.

If there is one, please *edit* your original question, and add the new information at the bottom. Use the `edit` link/button for that.